# Region bounded by planes in terms of inequalities

Tags: regions, computational-geometry

Suppose I have 5 planes that intersect to give a bounded region in 4D.
For example, the planes are

```
    x1==0;
    x2==0;
    x3==0;
    x4==0;
    x1+x2+x3+x4==1;
```

How can I tell Mathematica to find the region bounded by these planes, which is `x1>0&&x2>0&&x3>0&&x4>0&&x1+x2+x3+x4<1`?
The above example is very simple and intuitive but I often have 5 planes in 4d which are not intuitive to obtain the bounded region, so an automatized method will be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a set of variables `vars` and a set of planes `planes`, where each plane is an equation set to zero,

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
planes = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 - 1};
```

the question is: on which side of each plane is the desired polytope? For $n$ planes there are $2^n$ possible polytopes:

```
polytopes =
  Inner[#1 #2 > 0 &, Tuples[{-1, 1}, Length[planes]], planes, And]

(*    {-x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       -x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0, 
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && -x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && -x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && -x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0,
       x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && -1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 > 0}    *)
```

Of these 32 polytopes, select the ones that have a nonzero (but finite) 4-volume:

```
Select[polytopes, 
  0 < RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[#, Evaluate[vars]], Length[vars]] < Infinity &]

(*    {x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0}    *)
```

For large numbers of planes, this exhaustive search may be infeasible.

#### Faster method based on @flinty's suggestion

A very much faster (but as yet unproven) solution follows @flinty's suggestion of first finding the point $Q$ that minimizes the sum of squared distances to the planes.

Parametrizing the planes in the form

```
vars = {x1, x2, x3, x4};
planes = {{{1, 0, 0, 0}, 0},
          {{0, 1, 0, 0}, 0},
          {{0, 0, 1, 0}, 0},
          {{0, 0, 0, 1}, 0},
          {{1, 1, 1, 1}, 1}};
```

so that their equations are

```
#[[1]].vars == #[[2]] & /@ planes
(*    {x1 == 0,
       x2 == 0,
       x3 == 0,
       x4 == 0,
       x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 1}    *)
```

we calculate the squared distances of a point $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\}$ to each plane with

```
(vars.#[[1]] - #[[2]])^2/#[[1]].#[[1]] & /@ planes
(*    {x1^2,
       x2^2,
       x3^2,
       x4^2,
       1/4 (-1 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x4)^2}    *)
```

The point that minimizes the sum of these squared distances can be found through a minimization,

```
Minimize[Total[%], vars]
(*    {1/8, {x1 -> 1/8, x2 -> 1/8, x3 -> 1/8, x4 -> 1/8}}    *)
```

or directly (much faster) by solving a linear system of equations:

```
Q = LinearSolve[
      Total[KroneckerProduct[#[[1]], #[[1]]]/#[[1]].#[[1]] & /@ planes],
      Total[(#[[1]] #[[2]])/#[[1]].#[[1]] & /@ planes]]
(*    {1/8, 1/8, 1/8, 1/8}    *)
```

Once we know the point $Q$, we know on which side of each plane the polytope lies:

```
Sign[#[[1]].Q - #[[2]]] & /@ planes
(*    {1, 1, 1, 1, -1}    *)
```

We assemble the inequalities for the polytope with

```
polytope =
  And @@ (Sign[#[[1]].Q - #[[2]]] (#[[1]].vars - #[[2]]) > 0 & /@ planes)

(*    x1 > 0 && x2 > 0 && x3 > 0 && x4 > 0 && 1 - x1 - x2 - x3 - x4 > 0    *)
```

and verify that this polytope has a finite volume:

```
RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[polytope, Evaluate[vars]], Length[vars]]
(*    1/24    *)
```

Comment: Is it possible the search could be cut down by knowing in advance a point on the interior of the region?

Comment: Of course: if you know a single point inside of the polytope, then it's trivial to find out which side of each plane you're on.

Comment: yes in that case, if we had an intractable number of planes and it was too expensive to search using the above method, could we start off with a random point $p_0$ and 'nudge' that point by gradient descent in the direction that minimizes the total minimum distance to all planes using `RegionNearest`? Eventually $p_n$ ends up on the interior of the region after a number of steps. And then that point can be used to determine the inequality. Does that make sense?

Comment: See update: I think your suggestion can be made into an efficient solution.

Comment: you've said OP's suggestion - but I'm not the OP

Comment: @flinty oops, thanks.